# Grid columns using flexbox with fixed size margin gutters

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid-layout

Is it possible to apply a fixed margin (e.g. 5px) to a cell in a flexbox layout, where the row space is evenly distributed among its columns?

Want I want to achieve:

[image: this is the desired layout]

My current CSS will only align 3 columns in one row:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fm4v13jc/1/)

```css
.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px green;
}

.col {
    flex: 0 0 25%;
    text-align: center;
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px blue;
    background-color: steelblue;
 
 margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
  <div class="panel">1</div>
 </div>
    <div class="col">
  <div class="panel">2</div>
 </div>
    <div class="col">
  <div class="panel">3</div>
 </div>
    <div class="col">
  <div class="panel">4</div>
 </div>
 <div class="col"><div class="panel">5</div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) for `flex-basis` length (in your case — it's in shorthand property `flex`), `10px` because `margin-left: 5px` and `margin-right: 5px`:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/9fjy1512/1/)

```css
.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px green;
}

.col {
    flex: 0 0 calc(25% - 10px);
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px blue;
    background-color: steelblue;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="panel">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="panel">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="panel">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="panel">4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="panel">5</div>
    </div>
</div>
```